# Read two YAML files and compare the modules that appear in both

Tags: perl, yaml, difference

I am trying to compare two YAML files as follows

- Ignore all commented lines
- If the files have the same modules then compare those modules' versions
- If the versions are different then print the differences to file `output.log` and raise an error

#### file1.yml

```yaml
Modules:
     python:
         PATH: /cfg/python/version-1.0
     c:
         PATH: /cfg/c/release-1.2.0
     c++:
         PATH: /cfg/c++/release-1.1.5
     java:
         PATH: /cfg/java/version-2.157
     #connect:
     #    PATH: /cfg/connect/release-1.2.3
```

#### file2.yml

```yaml
Modules:
     python:
         PATH: /cfg/python/version-1.1
     c:
         PATH: /cfg/c/release-1.2.0
     java:
         PATH: /cfg/java/version-2.161
     eclipse:
         PATH: /cfg/eclipse/version-4.5
     #connect:
     #    PATH: /cfg/connect/release-1.2.0
```

#### Desired output

```
Error:
  File1.yml - python: PATH: /cfg/python/verison-1.0
  file2.yml - python: PATH: /cfg/python/verison-1.1
Error:
  file1.yml - java: PATH: /cfg/java/version-2.157
  file2.yml - java: PATH: /cfg/java/version-2.161
```

#### My code

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;

open f1, "file1.yml" or die "couldn't open the file: $! \n ";
my @line1 = <f1>;
close(f1);

open f2, "file2.yml" or die "couldn't open the file: $! \n ";
my @line2 = <f2>;
close(f2);

open( OUT, ">", "error.txt" );

for ( my $i = 0; $i < @line1; $i++ ) {

    for ( my $j = 0; $j < @line2; $j++ ) {

        if ( $line1[$i] =~ $line2[$j] ) {
            print OUT "Match Found: \n $line1[$i] \n $line2[$j]";
        }
    }
}
close OUT;
```

#### output

```
Match Found:
    Modules:
    Modules:
 Match Found:
    python:
    python:
 Match Found:
    c:
    c: 
 Match Found:
    java:
    java:
 Match Found:
    #connect:
    #connect:
```

Comment: The whitespace in YAML is important, but how much of it there is is not, as long as it's consistent. You should really use a YAML parser. I assume you are not only new to Perl, but also new to programing, so here's some advice from a veteran in both. Programming is solving problems. If the problem seems to hard, try to break it down into smaller pieces. In your case, you want to compare data. First, you need to get it. YAML is serialization format. Deserialize it to put it into a data structure that Perl likes. Then compare. Now you have two smaller problems that are easier to tackle.

Comment: In addition to that, your desired output shows errors or mismatches (with a difference in whitespace, please *be consistent* and [edit] that), but your actual program deals with matches. That's not really not working, but rather doing something entirely different that you told it to. You're probably still in the process of getting to the right thing and got stuck. Please tell us where you got stuck. How were you thinking to get to the solution, why are you now stuck at this particular step?

Comment: Thank you so much for giving some very important basic information. :) I am stuck at the point after i do the if condition. if condition checks for the for the matching module in both the files. Once i get the matching modules, i want to increment a line and compare the next line for  their version. Then print the modules that are present in both the file with different versions.

Comment: You say you're trying to compare two files according to some rules, but all you have written is `$line1[$i] =~ $line2[$j]`. Surely you can't expect that to ignore commented lines and compare the versions of matching modules? You really need to make an attempt at writing some code before we can help you with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is technically not really anything wrong with your program, so I am not going to offer a fix or an explanation. You wrote different code than what you were trying to solve.

Instead, I will show you a different approach, step by step. First, remember that YAML is a data structure description. You can read that into Perl and convert it to a native data structure that Perl understands, instead of working with text comparison. Both your files have a similar structure, which makes this very simple.

Reading a data structure and converting it to a different format is hard. Luckily, one of Perl's many strengths is that a lot of problems have been solved already, and are available on the CPAN.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use YAML 'LoadFile';

my $file1 = LoadFile('file1.yml');
my $file2 = LoadFile('file2.yml');
```

This program will read both your files and convert the YAML data structures inside to Perl hash references using [`LoadFile` from the YAML module](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/YAML/lib/YAML.pod#LoadFile(filepath)).

On its own that is of course not very useful. So let's check what these structures look like. [Data::Dumper](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Dumper) is very useful for that, and it comes with your Perl installation. (Personally I would use [Data::Printer](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Printer), as I consider the output more readable, but that's up to you).

```
use Data::Dumper;

print Dumper $file1;
print Dumper $file2;
```

This will show us:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'Modules' => {
                       'java' => {
                                 'PATH' => '/cfg/java/version-2.157'
                               },
                       'c' => {
                              'PATH' => '/cfg/c/release-1.2.0'
                            },
                       'c++' => {
                                'PATH' => '/cfg/c++/release-1.1.5'
                              },
                       'python' => {
                                   'PATH' => '/cfg/python/verison-1.0'
                                 }
                     }
        };
$VAR1 = {
          'Modules' => {
                       'c' => {
                              'PATH' => '/cfg/c/release-1.2.0'
                            },
                       'java' => {
                                 'PATH' => '/cfg/java/version-2.161'
                               },
                       'python' => {
                                   'PATH' => '/cfg/python/verison-1.1'
                                 },
                       'eclipse' => {
                                    'PATH' => '/cfg/eclipse/version-4.5'
                                  }
                     }
        };
```

Notice how the keys are not in the same order they were in the files. That's because hashes in Perl are *unordered*. That's a feature. To get output that is consistently the same, we need to [`sort`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sort.html) those keys later on.

So we see that both structures have a key *Modules*. Inside, there is another hash reference, that has the languages as keys, and in each of those, there is another hash reference with exactly one *PATH* key and a value. We are interested in the value of each *PATH* for every language.

To get the languages, we iterate the `keys` of the *Modules* of one of the two files. We can then compare the values all the way down. If they are [not equal](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/ne.html), we print the error message.

```
use v5.10; # to get say

# get shortcuts so the lines are not as long
my $modules1 = $file1->{Modules};
my $modules2 = $file2->{Modules};
foreach my $language (sort keys %{ $file1->{Modules} }) {
    if ($modules1->{$language}->{PATH} ne $modules2->{$language}->{PATH} ) {
        say "Error:";
        say "file1.yml - $language: PATH: $modules1->{$language}->{PATH}";
        say "file2.yml - $language: PATH: $modules2->{$language}->{PATH}";
    }
}
```

I'm using [`say`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/say.html) instead of [`print`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/print.html), which attaches a newline at the end for us. The additional variables `$modules1` and `$modules2` are just to make the code easier to read, because `$file1->{Modules}->{$language}->{PATH}` is quite long.

Now if we run our program up to this point, we will get the following output.

```
Error:
file1.yml - c++: PATH: /cfg/c++/release-1.1.5
file2.yml - c++: PATH: 
Error:
file1.yml - java: PATH: /cfg/java/version-2.157
file2.yml - java: PATH: /cfg/java/version-2.161
Error:
file1.yml - python: PATH: /cfg/python/verison-1.0
file2.yml - python: PATH: /cfg/python/verison-1.1
Use of uninitialized value in string ne at /home/simbabque/code/scratch/scratch.pl line 133.
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at /home/simbabque/code/scratch/scratch.pl line 136.
```

That's almost what we want, but there are some pesky warnings (because we have `use warnings` turned on), and there is no value for *c++*. We need to filter out languages that only exist in one of the two files.

The languages that only exist in *file2.yml* are already not considered, because we only look at keys from *file1.yml*. To remove the ones from the first file, we have to check if they [`exist`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/exists.html) in the other before we access them.

```
next unless exists $modules2->{$language};
```

The [`unless` keyword](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/unless.html) is like `if (not ...)`, and I consider it much easier to read, especially in this very concise [*post-fix notation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation). Now the program gives the expected output.

```
Error:
file1.yml - java: PATH: /cfg/java/version-2.157
file2.yml - java: PATH: /cfg/java/version-2.161
Error:
file1.yml - python: PATH: /cfg/python/verison-1.0
file2.yml - python: PATH: /cfg/python/verison-1.1
```

Here is the whole thing. Don't forget to remove Data::Dumper from the code, as it has nothing to do in a production program. We were using it solely as a debugging aide.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use YAML 'LoadFile';

my $file1 = LoadFile('file1.yml');
my $file2 = LoadFile('file2.yml');

use v5.10;

# get shortcuts so the lines are not as long
my $modules1 = $file1->{Modules};
my $modules2 = $file2->{Modules};
foreach my $language (sort keys %{ $file1->{Modules} }) {
    next unless exists $modules2->{$language};
    if ($modules1->{$language}->{PATH} ne $modules2->{$language}->{PATH} ) {
        say "Error:";
        say "file1.yml - $language: PATH: $modules1->{$language}->{PATH}";
        say "file2.yml - $language: PATH: $modules2->{$language}->{PATH}";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for such a clear explanation! it helps me a lot. I tried the code you gave here but i dont see anything printing! i tried inserting other say statements through out the code, it all got printed but the say commands after "foreach" condition doesnt  not print! :(

Comment: @user3798648 are the files there? Did you install the YAML module?

Comment: Yes, the files are there. But i am sure if the YAML is installed. If it is not installed, shouldn't i be getting error when executing the file?

Comment: @user3798648 yeah in theory you should. Do `perl -MYAML\ 99` on the command line. What does it say? Do you get any other errors? Did you check if the `$file1` and `$file2` variables are set? Are the keys _Modules_ and _PATH_ the same in the files?

Comment: You're assuming that there is only a single module per language, but that is not the nature of modules. I think the OP needs to split each `PATH` into `my ( $module, $version ) = $path =~ m|(.*)/(.*)|` and compare `$version` if `$path` matches.

Comment: @Borodin that's entirely possible. But they only gave us this example, so I worked with it.

Comment: Sure, but in the example `$module` is always the same for a given language, so either interpretation would work. I guess we'll find out if it's the wrong guess!

Comment: This is what it says: perl -MYAML\ 99
YAML version 99 required--this is only version 0.84.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted. Is there a way to do this script without using YAML?

Comment: @user3798648 we just proved you have a recent version of YAML. It must be something else. Is there really no error message? Are your files exactly like the ones you showed on the question? .

Comment: No, there is no error message! and i tried dumping the contents with Dumper, it works.

Comment: Its working :) I had my "Modules" is full caps . Once i changes that, it worked :) Thank you so much @simbabque, i really learnt some useful stuff :)

Comment: @user3798648 you're welcome. Probably the most important lesson you learned is that in programming tiny details matter. :-) Please have a look at [ask] to see what to do here on Stack Overflow when someone answers your question. Thanks.